# SQL Server XQuery - iterate dynamic xml and return custom structure

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlxml, xquery-sql

I have below XML in SQL Server and wants to iterate over it in order to generate a structured message.

```
<aggregate type="ApplicationForm">
    <entity type="Form" root="true" id="d799728b-7973-4046-b60f-cb25d4ee385c">
        <attribute name="creationDate" multivalue="false">2017-01-16</attribute>
        <attribute name="product" multivalue="false">Abc</attribute>
        <relation name="r_PersonMain" multivalue="false">4808f654-f480-412c-8dc5-d29c6c811602</relation>         
        <relation name="r_PersonPayer" multivalue="false">a8e9eaf2-56a5-4f88-955b-19eb98f6e882</relation>
    </entity>
    <entity type="Payment" root="true" id="e197bf66-1e35-42a9-bdc0-0674e3a0f765">
        <attribute name="totalAnnualPremium" multivalue="false">328415.81</attribute>
        <relation name="r_PaymentMethodRecurring" multivalue="false">b8b3c652-b886-44aa-a75b-b2d3ecd6c064</relation>
        <relation name="r_PaymentMethodFirst" multivalue="false">f3d91f99-ff6a-4888-a663-24e42ecc7342</relation>
        <attribute name="term" multivalue="false">01</attribute>         
    </entity>
    <entity type="Person" root="false" id="4808f654-f480-412c-8dc5-d29c6c811602">
        <relation name="r_AddressWork" multivalue="false">cae83657-47c2-49bd-a588-7685271c4766</relation>
        <attribute name="idNumber" multivalue="false">1112223334447</attribute>  
        <relation name="r_SelectionItem" multivalue="true">...</relation>
        <relation name="r_Health" multivalue="false">07d08bd6-ec73-4710-9de4-23435cd2b088</relation>     
        <relation name="r_AddressCurrent" multivalue="false">56d17bda-e332-497e-8e22-e7b7f09f996d</relation>
        <attribute name="lastName" multivalue="false"> 1</attribute>         
        <attribute name="jobDescription1" multivalue="false"/>
        <relation name="r_Behavior" multivalue="false">2db2c23a-37dd-4857-87b4-005aa87b2c2d</relation>       
        <attribute name="email" multivalue="false"></attribute>      
        <relation name="r_AddressRegistered" multivalue="false">ce79a468-fb26-4996-91a8-82954d960855</relation>
        <attribute name="telephoneExtention1" multivalue="false"/>
        <relation name="r_Occupation1" multivalue="false">b7b69acc-2945-4f64-8ffd-4537849280f5</relation>        
    </entity>
</aggregate>
```

The top element contains long list of `entity` tags. Each of it contains two elements, `attribute` & `relation`. The `attribute` contains direct values while the `relation` contains reference to another `entity` tag which in turn contains either `attribute` or `relation`.

In order to pick out `entity` Form (1st tag), it requires to iterate on it and all of its references until all referenced `entities` are retrieved.

I can retrieve first entity and its relations (reference entities) and then I access its 2nd level referenced entity and then i again check inside of it if there is another "relation" tag then I have to access it as well.

Problem is, this approach is not dynamic and can not automatically retrieve all referenced items.

Q:- How I can dynamically access all referenced entities and its attributes until there is no referenced entity anymore.

Q:- I also want to give assign tag my custom names based on each attribute or entity "name" tag. for example, creationDate, product.

Here is my query.

```
DECLARE @xml xml
  SET @xml =(Select CAST( CAST([AAHAD].[dbo].[aq_aggregate].data AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XML ) 
        FROM  [AAHAD].[dbo].[aq_aggregate]  
        WHERE [AAHAD].[dbo].[aq_aggregate].[aggregateId] = 2 
        FOR XML RAW, TYPE)

 SELECT @xml.query('
    let $xml := (/row/aggregate)
    let $form := (/row/aggregate/entity[@type="Form"])

    return
    <Form>
        <attributes>
        {
            for $form_attrs in ($form/attribute)
            return  <attribute><name>{ data($form_attrs/@name) } </name><value>{ data($form_attrs) }</value></attribute>
        }
        </attributes>
        <relations>
        {
             for $form_rel in ($form/relation)
             let $form_rel_id := data($form_rel)
             let $relation :=($xml/entity[@id=$form_rel_id])

             return  
             <relation>           
                  <attributes>
                    {
                        for $innerRel_attrs in ($relation/attribute)
                        return  <attribute><name>{ data($innerRel_attrs/@name) } </name><value>{ data($innerRel_attrs) }</value></attribute>
                    }
                   </attributes>
                   <relations>
                    {
                         for $innerRel_rel in ($relation/relation)
                         let $inner_Rel_id := data($innerRel_rel)
                         let $inner_Relation :=($xml/entity[@id=$inner_Rel_id])

                         return  
                         <relation>           
                              <attributes>
                                {
                                    for $inner2Rel_attrs in ($inner_Relation/attribute)
                                    return  <attribute><name>{ data($inner2Rel_attrs/@name) } </name><value>{ data($inner2Rel_attrs) }</value></attribute>
                                }
                               </attributes>
                               <relations>
                                {
                                     for $inner2Rel_rel in ($inner_Relation/relation)                         
                                     return <relation>{ ($inner2Rel_rel) }</relation>
                                }
                                </relations>               
                         </relation>
                    }
                    </relations>               
             </relation>
         }
        </relations>         
    </Form>
  ')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but I'll use a Table-Valued-Function to dynamically parse virtually any XML structure into a hierarchy of Elements, Attributes, and Values.  The results may be processed and/or pivoted via the range keys (R1/R2) or XPath.

The original source was http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10495/xquery-lab-58-select-from-xml.aspx  Only made a few tweaks from the original.

The performance is respectable.  Your sample XML was processed in 170 ms.

Since you are on 2008, I should note that you would have to edit the CONCAT() portions.

**Example:**

```
Select * From [dbo].[udf-XML-Hier](@XML) Order By R1
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-XML-Hier](@XML xml)

Returns Table 
As Return

with  cte0 as (Select Lvl       = 1
                     ,ID        = Cast(1 as int) 
                     ,Pt        = Cast(NULL as int)
                     ,Element   = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                     ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(100))
                     ,Value     = x.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)')
                     ,XPath     = cast(concat(x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),'[' ,cast(Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(1000))
                     ,Seq       = cast(1000000+Row_Number() over (Order by (Select NULL)) as varchar(1000))
                     ,AttData   = x.query('.') 
                     ,XMLData   = x.query('*') 
               From   @XML.nodes('/*') a(x) 
               Union  All
               Select Lvl       = p.Lvl + 1 
                     ,ID        = Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10
                     ,Pt        = p.ID
                     ,Element   = c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                     ,Attribute = cast('' as varchar(100))
                     ,Value     = cast( c.value('text()[1]','varchar(max)') as varchar(max) ) 
                     ,XPath     = cast(concat(p.XPath,'/',c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)'),'[',cast(Row_Number() Over(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') Order By (Select 1)) as int),']') as varchar(1000) )
                     ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+Cast( (Lvl + 1) * 1024 + (Row_Number() Over(Order By (Select 1)) * 2) as int ) * 10) as varchar(1000))
                     ,AttData   = c.query('.') 
                     ,XMLData   = c.query('*') 
               From   cte0 p 
               Cross  Apply p.XMLData.nodes('*') b(c) )
    , cte1 as (Select R1 = Row_Number() over (Order By Seq),A.*
               From  (Select  Lvl,ID,Pt,Element,Attribute,Value,XPath,Seq From cte0
                      Union All
                      Select Lvl       = p.Lvl+1
                            ,ID        = p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
                            ,Pt        = p.ID
                            ,Element   = p.Element
                            ,Attribute = x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                            ,Value     = x.value('.','varchar(max)')
                            ,XPath     = p.XPath + '/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                            ,Seq       = cast(concat(p.Seq,' ',10000000+p.ID + Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) ) as varchar(1000))
                      From   cte0 p 
                      Cross  Apply AttData.nodes('/*/@*') a(x) 
                     ) A )
Select A.R1
      ,R2  = IsNull((Select max(R1) From cte1 Where Seq Like A.Seq+'%'),A.R1)
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Pt
      ,A.Element
      ,A.Attribute
      ,A.XPath
      ,Title = Replicate('|---',Lvl-1)+Element+case when Attribute='' then '' else '@'+Attribute end
      ,A.Value
 From  cte1 A

/*
Source: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10495/xquery-lab-58-select-from-xml.aspx

Declare @XML xml='<person><firstname preferred="Annie" nickname="BeBe">Annabelle</firstname><lastname>Smith</lastname></person>'
Select * from [dbo].[udf-XML-Hier](@XML) Order by R1
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You tell us that you want to

> generate a structued message

It would help to show the expected output...

The following code will extract all data of your XML in one easy to query *derived table*.

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<aggregate type="ApplicationForm">
    <entity type="Form" root="true" id="d799728b-7973-4046-b60f-cb25d4ee385c">
        <attribute name="creationDate" multivalue="false">2017-01-16</attribute>
        <attribute name="product" multivalue="false">Abc</attribute>
        <relation name="r_PersonMain" multivalue="false">4808f654-f480-412c-8dc5-d29c6c811602</relation>         
        <relation name="r_PersonPayer" multivalue="false">a8e9eaf2-56a5-4f88-955b-19eb98f6e882</relation>
    </entity>
    <entity type="Payment" root="true" id="e197bf66-1e35-42a9-bdc0-0674e3a0f765">
        <attribute name="totalAnnualPremium" multivalue="false">328415.81</attribute>
        <relation name="r_PaymentMethodRecurring" multivalue="false">b8b3c652-b886-44aa-a75b-b2d3ecd6c064</relation>
        <relation name="r_PaymentMethodFirst" multivalue="false">f3d91f99-ff6a-4888-a663-24e42ecc7342</relation>
        <attribute name="term" multivalue="false">01</attribute>         
    </entity>
    <entity type="Person" root="false" id="4808f654-f480-412c-8dc5-d29c6c811602">
        <relation name="r_AddressWork" multivalue="false">cae83657-47c2-49bd-a588-7685271c4766</relation>
        <attribute name="idNumber" multivalue="false">1112223334447</attribute>  
        <relation name="r_SelectionItem" multivalue="true">...</relation>
        <relation name="r_Health" multivalue="false">07d08bd6-ec73-4710-9de4-23435cd2b088</relation>     
        <relation name="r_AddressCurrent" multivalue="false">56d17bda-e332-497e-8e22-e7b7f09f996d</relation>
        <attribute name="lastName" multivalue="false"> 1</attribute>         
        <attribute name="jobDescription1" multivalue="false"/>
        <relation name="r_Behavior" multivalue="false">2db2c23a-37dd-4857-87b4-005aa87b2c2d</relation>       
        <attribute name="email" multivalue="false"></attribute>      
        <relation name="r_AddressRegistered" multivalue="false">ce79a468-fb26-4996-91a8-82954d960855</relation>
        <attribute name="telephoneExtention1" multivalue="false"/>
        <relation name="r_Occupation1" multivalue="false">b7b69acc-2945-4f64-8ffd-4537849280f5</relation>        
    </entity>
</aggregate>';
```

--The query

```
WITH AllValues AS
(
    SELECT @xml.value(N'(/aggregate/@type)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Aggregate_Type
          ,e.value(N'@type',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Entity_Type
          ,e.value(N'@root',N'bit') AS Entity_Root
          ,e.value(N'@id',N'uniqueidentifier') AS [Entity_Id]
          ,nd.value(N'local-name(.)',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Node_Type
          ,nd.value(N'@name',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Node_Name
          ,nd.value(N'@multivalue',N'bit') AS Node_MultiValue
          ,nd.value(N'text()[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Node_Content
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/aggregate/entity') AS A(e)
    CROSS APPLY e.nodes(N'*') AS B(nd)
)
SELECT * FROM AllValues;
```

The result (named and (if possible) typed):

```
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| Aggregate_Type  | Entity_Type | Entity_Root | Entity_Id                            | Node_Type | Node_Name                | Node_MultiValue | Node_Content                         |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Form        | 1           | D799728B-7973-4046-B60F-CB25D4EE385C | attribute | creationDate             | 0               | 2017-01-16                           |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Form        | 1           | D799728B-7973-4046-B60F-CB25D4EE385C | attribute | product                  | 0               | Abc                                  |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Form        | 1           | D799728B-7973-4046-B60F-CB25D4EE385C | relation  | r_PersonMain             | 0               | 4808f654-f480-412c-8dc5-d29c6c811602 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Form        | 1           | D799728B-7973-4046-B60F-CB25D4EE385C | relation  | r_PersonPayer            | 0               | a8e9eaf2-56a5-4f88-955b-19eb98f6e882 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Payment     | 1           | E197BF66-1E35-42A9-BDC0-0674E3A0F765 | attribute | totalAnnualPremium       | 0               | 328415.81                            |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Payment     | 1           | E197BF66-1E35-42A9-BDC0-0674E3A0F765 | relation  | r_PaymentMethodRecurring | 0               | b8b3c652-b886-44aa-a75b-b2d3ecd6c064 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Payment     | 1           | E197BF66-1E35-42A9-BDC0-0674E3A0F765 | relation  | r_PaymentMethodFirst     | 0               | f3d91f99-ff6a-4888-a663-24e42ecc7342 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Payment     | 1           | E197BF66-1E35-42A9-BDC0-0674E3A0F765 | attribute | term                     | 0               | 01                                   |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | relation  | r_AddressWork            | 0               | cae83657-47c2-49bd-a588-7685271c4766 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | attribute | idNumber                 | 0               | 1112223334447                        |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | relation  | r_SelectionItem          | 1               | ...                                  |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | relation  | r_Health                 | 0               | 07d08bd6-ec73-4710-9de4-23435cd2b088 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | relation  | r_AddressCurrent         | 0               | 56d17bda-e332-497e-8e22-e7b7f09f996d |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | attribute | lastName                 | 0               | 1                                    |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | attribute | jobDescription1          | 0               | NULL                                 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | relation  | r_Behavior               | 0               | 2db2c23a-37dd-4857-87b4-005aa87b2c2d |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | attribute | email                    | 0               | NULL                                 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | relation  | r_AddressRegistered      | 0               | ce79a468-fb26-4996-91a8-82954d960855 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | attribute | telephoneExtention1      | 0               | NULL                                 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
| ApplicationForm | Person      | 0           | 4808F654-F480-412C-8DC5-D29C6C811602 | relation  | r_Occupation1            | 0               | b7b69acc-2945-4f64-8ffd-4537849280f5 |
+-----------------+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I can see, that the `Form` has a relation to person via person's id `4808F...` Similar to payer vai payer's id. But I have no idea, what you are going to do from here (are these relations 1:1 or 1:n?)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, though i was looking for similar hierarchical format to be generated and not tabular. So that all elements referenced via 'ID' should come as children to parent element.

Comment: @AAhad That is the reason, why you should always post the **expected output**. I have no idea (how should I?) what you need... This is not possible to answer if you do not provide further details (read my final lines). Following a chain of linked entities will lead into *recursive CTE*.

Comment: I was looking for ways to bring related entities under one parent element, thats what i was looking for.